# Visual Basic: displaying date as "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: vb.net, date, format

I just need a way to take a variable (a Date) and convert its format to dd/MM/yyyy for display.

I have a variable, how do I take that variable and turn it to dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do that depending on the platform, and it's such a commonplace task there are about just as many examples on the internet, including on this site. It would have taken you less time to figure this out doing a quick google search than it did to type out this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, every class in the .NET framework has a `.ToString()` method. For [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there exists an overload which takes a [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
' Make sure to use double slashes to escape them!
MyDate.ToString("dd//MM//yyyy")
```

This is *one* way to do this, but there are others using `string.Format`, an `IFormatProivder`, ect...

Comment: @ElGavilan He specifically titled the question "Visual Basic:-" - poor use of tags, but clearly shows he's using VB. If it's VBA, I'll rescind the answer, but that's a presumption I'm going to live with.

Comment: He must have ninja edited his title before I refreshed. I'll rescind my original comment.

Comment: This is fantastic, I cannot express enough how delighted I am to read this. This is perfect, it works, it's simple, I can understand it. I extend my eternal gratitude to you!

Also, sorry about the poor tag, I usually add the VB tag but my mind was wondering since I'd just spent the last hour or so trying to find guides to tell me this (my research skills are notoriously faulty).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
date1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```